# Symbols in symtab reordered between module.kld and module.ko?

Tags: linker, freebsd

I am comparing the readelf -s snapshot from module.kld and module.ko
for a module build  in a cross compiler FreeBSD 10 environment,

Do the symbols in symtab get reordered between module.kld and
module.ko, as an example

readelf -s module.kld we pick 2 symbols
  2651: 000b8230    74 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 prison_equal_ip6
  2652: 00030140  3318 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 ip_output

Compare them with readelf -s from module.ko
  2558: 0007a6d0  3318 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 ip_output
  2559: 001027c0    74 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 prison_equal_ip6

So the symbol ip_output appears after prison_equal_ip6 in module.kld
but appears before it in module.ko. The problem is this is affecting
the DTrace FBT probing, running FBT probe of ip_output shows as having
arguments of prison_equal_ip6.

The way module.ko is being derived from module.kld is
ld -m elf_i386 -Bshareable --verbose  -o module.ko.debug module.kld

How can I suppress this re-ordering?